# struts variable value in href id

Tags: struts2

I have Map   type.
I want to iterate over it using struts tag library.
now want to generate a token using { id + '_nav' } and set this token to id field of href.

Can You please help me out how to do that in struts?

The JSP Code :

```
<div class="box-heading">Quick Links</div>
<ul>
<s:set name="currentPage" value="currentNavigationPage"></s:set>

<s:iterator value="orderedSectionName_StartPageMap" >
    <s:if test="%{#currentPage > key}">
    <li><a id="{key + '_nav'}"  href="#" ><s:property value="value"/></a></li>
    </s:if>
    <s:else>
    <li><a href="#" ><s:property value="value"/></a></li>
    </s:else>

</s:iterator>
</ul>
```

Can u please suggest me , how can i appen key from map with '_nav' token ?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not tested you can try  something like

```
<s:iterator value="orderedSectionName_StartPageMap" var="mapObject" >
    <s:if test="%{#currentPage > key}">
    <li><a id="%{#key}__nav"  href="#" ><s:property value="value"/></a></li>
    </s:if>
    <s:else>
    <li><a href="#" ><s:property value="value"/></a></li>
    </s:else>

</s:iterator>
```

or

```
<li><a id='%{#key+"__nav"}'  href="#" ><s:property value="value"/></a></li>
```

Honestly i have not tested both of them myself

As update by the Zuned it will work with `<s:propert>` also

```
<li><a id='<s:property value="key"/>'  href="#" ><s:property value="value"/></a></li>
```

Comment: worked with  <li><a id='<s:property value="key"/>_nav'  href="#" ><s:property value="value"/></a></li>

Comment: Umesh as suggested By You .. I tried but didnt work so i'll go with <li><a id='<s:property value="key"/>_nav' href="#" ><s:property value="value"/></a></li> which is working fine. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: that's  perfectly fine.even i updated my answer with your inputs :)

Comment: Umesh do u have any idea if i want add to numeric 1 to this key how can i achieve that? Means want increment key value by one then want to append with token '_nav'. How could i achieve that ? And What could be the Better place to go through about these tags in detail with example?

Comment: I did not get your question properly,but you can just use a field and set that value in that use your mathematical operation and use that inside the tag.The best place to find tag reference is Apache tag reference page http://struts.apache.org/2.0.14/docs/tag-reference.html

Comment: <li><a id='%{<s:property value="key"/>+1}_nav' href="#" ><s:property value="value"/></a></li>  ---->> My key is Integer Value and want to add one before appending '_nav' token to it. How to do that in struts?

Comment: you can do something like this <s:set name="value1" value ="%{1}" /> and than inside your iterator tag  <s:set name="value1" value ="%{#value1+ key}" /> But JSP is more intented for presentation, not for some arithmetic stuff. More clean  way would be to just do the math in a bean and access the outcome the usual way

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
<s:a id="%{key}__nav"  href="#" ><s:property value="value"/></s:a>
```

instead of 
`<a id="%{#key}__nav"  href="#" ><s:property value="value"/></a>`